# XSL 1.0 Format table splitting values

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I've a sample xml input like the following:

```
<table name="Table1">
<fields>
   <field name="Field1" />
   <field name="Field2" />
   <field name="Field3" />
   <field name="Field4" />
</fields>
<data>
   <row value="2,Description1,A,AA" />
   <row value="3,Description2,B,BB" />
   <row value="7,Description3,C,CC" />
</data>
</table>
<table name="Table2">
<fields>
   <field name="Field7" />
   <field name="Field8" />
   <field name="Field9" />
</fields>
<data>
   <row value="Q,Description7,A" />
   <row value="W,Description8,B" />
   <row value="X,Description9,C" />
</data>
</table>
```

Please note that I can have many tables with different number of fields but row values contain always the exact number of fields required.

The expected result is an output like this:

```
<ListOfTable1>
<item>
   <Field1>2</Field1>
   <Field2>Description1</Field2>
   <Field3>A</Field3>
   <Field4>AA</Field4>
</item>
<item>
   <Field1>3</Field1>
   <Field2>Description2</Field2>
   <Field3>B</Field3>
   <Field4>BB</Field4>
</item>
<item>
   <Field1>7</Field1>
   <Field2>Description3</Field2>
   <Field3>C</Field3>
   <Field4>CC</Field4>
</item>
</ListOfTable1>

<ListOfTable2>
<item>
   <Field7>Q</Field7>
   <Field8>Description7</Field8>
   <Field9>A</Field9>
</item>
<item>
   <Field7>W</Field7>
   <Field8>Description8</Field8>
   <Field9>B</Field9>
</item>
<item>
   <Field7>X</Field7>
   <Field8>Description9</Field8>
   <Field9>C</Field9>
</item>
</ListOfTable2>
```

I can use only strict XSLT 1.0 unfortunately
No external functions or reference

I've been using a slightly modified version of third solution suggested

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="//table">
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;ListOf',@name,'&gt;')" />
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="concat('&lt;/ListOf',@name,'&gt;')" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table/data/row">
    <item>
      <xsl:call-template name="fldsplit">
        <xsl:with-param name="f" select="@value" />
        <xsl:with-param name="set" select="//fields/field" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="fldsplit">
    <xsl:param name="f" />
    <xsl:param name="set"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bfc" select="substring-before($f,',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="afc" select="substring-after($f,',')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$set/@name}">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$bfc">
          <xsl:value-of select="$bfc"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$f"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="$afc">
      <xsl:call-template name="fldsplit">
        <xsl:with-param name="f" select="$afc"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="set" select="$set/following-sibling::*" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But I have an issue with second table (or any other I add to the input), that is Fields name repeat themselves starting always from Field1 while I expect to use specific fields for each table parsed

This is current output (wrong)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<ListOfTable1>
   <item><Field1>2</Field1><Field2>Description1</Field2><Field3>A</Field3><Field4>AA</Field4></item>
   <item><Field1>3</Field1><Field2>Descritpion2</Field2><Field3>B</Field3><Field4>BB</Field4></item>
   <item><Field1>7</Field1><Field2>Description3</Field2><Field3>C</Field3><Field4>CC</Field4></item>
</ListOfTable1>
<ListOfTable2>
   <item><Field1>Q</Field1><Field2>Description7</Field2><Field3>A</Field3></item>
   <item><Field1>W</Field1><Field2>Description8</Field2><Field3>B</Field3></item>
   <item><Field1>X</Field1><Field2>Description9</Field2><Field3>C</Field3></item>
</ListOfTable2>
```

Comment: Hey, if you change the initial conditions several times, then it's not a question anymore, it's a "please do my work" !...

Comment: Sorry Orabig, actually I didn't change the conditions since the initial structure to parse is the same but gets repeated inside the file. Your suggestion like the others works fine but currently all of them manage in a different way Fields and Rows. I'm trying to get around this cycling through tables but so far didn't get the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be certain that the only commas in the row value are the ones that separate fields (i.e. there's no "escape" mechanism like `"\,"`), and there will always be the right number of fields in every row, then a recursive approach will work.  I'm assuming here that there is a single root element named `root` enclosing your `table` elements in order to make the input well-formed.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <data>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="root/table" />
    </data>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
    <xsl:element name="ListOf{@name}">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="data/row"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <!-- add a trailing comma to the value so we don't lose the last field -->
    <xsl:variable name="val" select="concat(@value, ',')" />
    <item>
      <!-- use just the fields that belong to this table -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../fields/field[1]">
        <xsl:with-param name="thisVal" select="substring-before($val, ',')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($val, ',')" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="field">
    <xsl:param name="thisVal"/>
    <xsl:param name="rest"/>

    <xsl:element name="{@name}">
      <xsl:value-of select="$thisVal" />
    </xsl:element>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::field[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="thisVal" select="substring-before($rest, ',')" />
      <xsl:with-param name="rest" select="substring-after($rest, ',')" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The trick here is that we generate the `<Field1>` etc. elements by applying templates to the `field` elements in turn.  Thus there's no need for any explicit conditionals (`if` or `choose`) because the recursion will automatically stop at the last field when `following-sibling::field[1]` no longer selects anything.

Comment: @AndreaPappy I've adjusted my answer to handle more than one table in the same document, as per your latest edit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, this should work as expected :

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//row"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:variable name="field1" select="substring-before(@value,',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="field2" select="substring-after(@value,',')"/>
    <item>
       <Field1><xsl:value-of select="$field1"/></Field1>
       <Field2><xsl:value-of select="$field2"/></Field2>
    </item>
</xsl:template>
```

As you can see, I didn't use your  part (btw, the type="int" of Field2 doesn't seem to fit with the sample), because I didn't know how.
Is it supposed to be a number of fields ? (if there may be an undefined number of fields, then a recursive solution would be necessary...)

---

Edit :

Ok, I've manage to write a solution working with any number of fields :

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="allfields" match="field" use="count(preceding-sibling::field) + 1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//row"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <item>
    <xsl:call-template name="row">
        <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@value"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
    </item>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="row">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:param name="pos"/>
    <xsl:variable name="field1">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($value,',')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($value,',')"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$value"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="fieldNext" select="substring-after($value,',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="fieldName" select="key('allfields',$pos)/@name"/>
        <xsl:element name="{$fieldName}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$field1"/>
        </xsl:element>
        <xsl:if test="not($fieldNext='')">
            <xsl:call-template name="row">
                <xsl:with-param name="value" select="$fieldNext"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="pos" select="$pos + 1"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This show how XSLT1.0 is very not suited for such things...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that can handle multiple fields assuming it has a corresponding number of fields separated by a ,

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </result>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="table">
     <xsl:element name="ListOf{@Name}">
         <xsl:apply-templates />
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template match="data/row">
    <item>
      <xsl:call-template name="fldsplit">
        <xsl:with-param name="f" select="@value" />
        <xsl:with-param name="set" select="//fields/field" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </item>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="fldsplit">
    <xsl:param name="f" />
    <xsl:param name="set"/>
    <xsl:variable name="bfc" select="substring-before($f,',')"/>
    <xsl:variable name="afc" select="substring-after($f,',')"/>
    <xsl:element name="{$set/@name}">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$bfc">
          <xsl:value-of select="$bfc"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$f"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:element>
    <xsl:if test="$afc">
      <xsl:call-template name="fldsplit">
        <xsl:with-param name="f" select="$afc"/>
        <xsl:with-param name="set" select="$set/following-sibling::*" />
      </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I've been using your solution and it's almost perfect but i had to review a little the input file and so I'm having a small issue with fields name. Could you please elaborate a little your solution in order to use field names separated for esch possible input table? Thanks